# Search for clients with auto-release after rejection

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I am interested in the situation when the verifier rejected a client and then the same client received an auto-approval on another application.
I have a table with requests, all requests have a person_id.
The idea is that a client could have created 10 applications, where 9 times he was refused and 10 times he was auto-approved, so first I need to find the group of clients who were refused and then find the clients who were auto-approved after that on another application. You also need to make the closed_agreement field match, because otherwise you can accidentally pull up the application for another loan.

Please give me advice on what to do

```
WITH rejected_customers AS (
  SELECT person_id
  FROM application
  WHERE status_id = 9 -- rejection
  AND decision_code in (9185, 479, 481, 483, 487, 480) -- reasons for rejection 
),
auto_approved_customers AS (
  SELECT ap.person_id
  FROM application ap
  JOIN rejected_customers rc ON ap.person_id = rc.person_id
  WHERE ap.status_id= 8 -- approval
    AND ap.date_create > (SELECT MAX(date_create) FROM application WHERE person_id = ap.person_id AND status_id = 9) + INTERVAL '30 days')

SELECT distinct ac.person_id
FROM auto_approved_customers aac
JOIN application ac ON aac.person_id = ac.person_id
WHERE ac.closed_agreement = 8;
```

like if I see that after a month the client on a new request received auto-approval, then I want to study why this happened, what changed after the rejection a month ago.

| person_id | id | status_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121151 | 1545641 | 9 | 2022-03-21 |
| 121151 | 4654646 | 8 | 2022-04-21 |

Comment: 1) Please only tag a single RDBMS... not multiple. 2) please a [mre] with sample data and desired results.